# Images in a mySQL database

Tags: mysql, storage

I'm making a website for my brother's webcomic, which was previously hosted on Tumblr. What is the most efficient/logical option for storing the pictures?

1. Downloading and putting the path in the Db
2. Storing them in the database, base64-encoded
3. linking directly to the pictures on Tumblr

wat do?

Comment: Is he going to continue to upload to tumblr?

Comment: I'm planning on creating a really minimal cms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the tumblr site is going to remain active I would lean towards using the Tumblr API to get at the photos. You could then just write some javascript/jquery functions to display the images however you want.

I've done something similar in the past with Google Picasa Albums and it worked out pretty well.

http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#photo-posts

Just a little additional info, in the past I've found using jquery plugins sometimes makes it a bit mor simple to get at the data I'm looking for. 
Never used this one in particular but just a quick search and found this as an example of one that might be helpful.

https://github.com/Iaaan/jQuery-plugin-for-Tumblr-API